# Using rvest to read oddly quoted text

Tags: rvest

I have had a lot of success using `rvest` to read tables and standard html. I am having a problem at the moment with reading text that has multiple quotes in it. It seems that `rvest` adds a new letter (a-z) when a new line of quoted text appears after quoted text and a space.

Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(rvest)
read_html("https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/gen/1?lang=eng") %>% 
  html_node("#p3") %>%
  html_text()
```

The results is

```
"3 And God asaid, Let there be blight: and there was light."
```

the misspelled words being "asaid" and "blight". lol

For more reference, web inspector was used to look at the html structure.

```
<p class="verse" id="p3>
<span class="verse-number verse">3</span>
"And God "
"said"
", Let there be "
"light"
": and there was light."
</p>
```

I am wondering what a solution to this kind of poorly formatted text would be.

Comment: The issue here is that there are two footnotes, "a" and "b" which are hidden by default (scroll to the bottom and click "show footnotes". How to solve it, I'm still working on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for and click on "show footnotes", then inspect the page again, you'll see the problem. The extra letters "a" in "asaid" and "b" in "blight" are the text of hidden footnotes, wrapped in `sup` tags.

```
page <- read_html("https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/gen/1?lang=eng")
page %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//p[@id = 'p3']") %>% 
  html_structure()

[[1]]
<p#p3 .verse [data-aid]>
  <span.verse-number.verse>
    {text}
  {text}
  <a.footnote.study-note-ref [href, rel]>
    <sup.studyNoteMarker.dontHighlight>
      {text}
    {text}
  {text}
  <a.footnote.study-note-ref [href, rel]>
    <sup.studyNoteMarker.dontHighlight>
      {text}
    {text}
  {text}
```

So one solution (it's a bit of a messy hack) is to extract the `sup` nodes, then remove them from the nodeset.

```
footnotes <- page %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//p[@id = 'p3']//sup")

xml_remove(footnotes)
page %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//p[@id = 'p3']") %>% 
  html_text()

[1] "3 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light."
```